# How to find names not present in one file compared with another file using bash?

Tags: bash, sorting

I have two files with a bunch of names up to the Thousands. Some names contain duplicates which I don't care about, I would just like to know what names aren't in the list which are contained in the 1st list but not in the 2nd.

List 1:

```
Mark Davis 
Mark Davis 
Elizabeth Linsey 
Michelle Lark
John Smith
Emily Posvil
```

List 2:

```
Elizabeth Linsey 
John Smith
Emily Posivl
```

List I want (people who are in list 1 but not shown up in list 2), I dont care about duplicates
List 3:

```
Mark Davis 
Michelle Lark
```

or

```
Mark Davis
Mark Davis 
Michelle Lark
```

I have tried using `grep -v -F` with different arguments and `comm -1 -3`.

Comment: You tried `comm -1 -3`, but did you pass any files `comm` command? Which ones? Please don't describe what you did, _show_ what you did. `comm -1 -3` will __not__ show unique lines from first file and __not__ show lines present in both files. Maybe you want `comm -2 -3`? Also, did you sort the files?

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried both and neither are producing the results I want. You mentioned sorting. How would i sort the files so that comm can work to the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try:

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort list1) <(sort list2)
```

Result:

```
Emily Posvil
Mark Davis
Mark Davis
Michelle Lark
```

The line `Emily Posvil` is also displayed just because
there's a typo in the name:)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that you will want to make sure that your spelling is up to snuff. Emily was listed with Posvil and Posivl.

You can make use of a for loop to check in list1 for each name against list2

```
IFS=$'\n'     #Makes new lines the only seperator

for name in $(awk '{print $1 " " $2}' test1.txt); do 
        if ! grep -iwq "^${name}" test2.txt; then
                echo ${name}
        fi
done | sort | uniq

# One-liner version
IFS=$'\n'; for name in $(awk '{print $1 " " $2}' test1.txt); do if ! grep -iwq "^${name}" test2.txt; then echo ${name}; fi ; done | sort | uniq
```

This is probably not the most *efficient* but it definitely gets you there. The sort | uniq at the end could be done on individual files to maybe shorten the length of time it would take. Other useful notes:

- Maybe run this in a screen if there are lots of names as you
  suggested
- Could output to a file if you are expecting a lot of    resulsts `>>
  /path/to/file`

Comment: Good catch on the names, I manually typed the names and didnt review it (edited now).